# how do I set many-relationship property in a generic way

Tags: ios, core-data

I know I can do:

```
[managedObject setValue:val forKey:@"key"];
```

But how do I add an object to a many-relationship nsorderedset? I've got a feeling I can't just:

```
NSOrderedSet * set = [managedObject objectForKey:@"therelationship"];
[set addObject:relationshipObj];
[managedObject setValue:set forKey:@"therelationship"];
```

Or can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but since ios4.0 they've been trying to stray away from setting values on NSManagedObjects with KVO. Apple wants you to make an NSManagedObject subclass. You're implementation would become something like this.

```
[[MyManagedObject theRelationshipSet] addObject:newRelationshipObject];
```

check out the "mastering coredata" in the wwdc 2010 video set.

Comment: He doesn't want to use KVO (key-value-observing), he wants to use KVC (key-value-coding) which are two different things altogether.

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend is to implement a convenience method like this on your NSManagedObject subclass:

```
- (NSMutableOrderedSet *)mutableAuthors;
{
    return [self mutableOrderedSetValueForKey:@"authors"];
}
```

This let's you call

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *authors = [mo mutableAuthors];
[authors insertObject:a atIndex:4];
```

or simply

```
[mo.mutableAuthors insertObject:a atIndex:4]
```

Comment: I've actually just finished a generic way to load plist data into target core data entities based on the name of the plist etc. To do that I had to set (and look up the relationships to set) in a generic way. Thanks for your answer though.